# C pointers and string

Tags: c++, pointers

Can any body tell me ,why my last line prints the enteir string instead of an address

```
char str [20];
char *sp;
cin>>str;
sp=str;
cout<<&str[0];
```

Comment: `str` and `&str[0]` are equivalent from the `cout` point of view -- both are a pointer to the first char in `str`.

Comment: Yes,but why it is spreading to entire string ?

Comment: It is explained in the duplicate, you need to cast to a pointer `(void *)str`

Comment: @KuttanSujith because the `operator<<(char*)` overload is designed to treat the pointer as a null terminated C string. You are looking for `operator<<(void*)` instead, which just prints the pointer address